# How to pass an HTML string to javascript function in a UIWebView, iOS

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, ios5, uiwebview

How can I pass a HTML string markup read from a file in objective C and pass it to a javascript function that takes a parameter ?

In my webViewDidFinishLoad I try to call like this

```
NSString *jsfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"setcontent" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsfile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&errDes];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"showHtml('%@');", filecontent]];
```

my javascript file is loaded with a function

```
function showHtml(param1)
{
    alert(param1);
    document.getElementById('section1').innerHTML = param1;
}
```

I tested this piece of code with explicit string values such as `@"<p id=\"cid1\"> test </p>"` and it works by setting the element contents. If I change this to `@"<p id='cid1'> test </p>"` i.e. with single quotes to the id attribute, it is not working. In order for the latter to work, I have to change the string formatter '%@' to \"%@\" in objective C code.

the above problem is not that serious but it is not working either way when reading the contents of a resource file containing multiple html tags that has to be set as an innerHTML  to the #section1 to a div element.

Do I need to encode the contents somehow  ? before calling the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method ?
Can anyone give me point me, what am I doing wrong ? if anyone know a better way to do this, please write.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

there is a length limit here and you seem to run into it when passing a whole file to js